# Get similar employees based on their attribute values

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, window-functions

Consider the following sample table("Customer") with these records

```
=========
Customer
=========
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| customer-id | att-a | att-b | att-c | att-d | att-e | att-f | att-g | att-h | att-i | att-j |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| customer-1 | att-a-7 | att-b-3 | att-c-10 | att-d-10 | att-e-15 | att-f-11 | att-g-2 | att-h-7 | att-i-5 | att-j-14 |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| customer-2 | att-a-9 | att-b-7 | att-c-12 | att-d-4 | att-e-10 | att-f-4 | att-g-13 | att-h-4 | att-i-1 | att-j-13 |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| customer-3 | att-a-10 | att-b-6 | att-c-1 | att-d-1 | att-e-13 | att-f-12 | att-g-9 | att-h-6 | att-i-7 | tt-j-4 |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| customer-19 | att-a-7 | att-b-9 | att-c-13 | att-d-5 | att-e-8 | att-f-5 | att-g-12 | att-h-14 | att-i-13 | att-j-15 |
--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have these records and many more records dumped into SQL database and wanted to find top 10 similar customer based on the attribute value. For example **customer-1** and **customer-19** have atleast one column value matching .i.e **"att-a-7"** so the output should give me 2 customer-id's or top similar customer that are **customer-1** and **customer-19**.
P.S - there can be one or more columns similar across rows.

I'm using windowing technique to find top 10 similar customer and im not sure if I'm correct.

following is my approach I used in my query  :

```
 row_number() over (partition by att-a, att-b,..,att-j order by customer-id) as customers
```

is this correct. ?

Comment: What is your Oracle version? `11g` ? `12c`?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy its a SQL server, not Oracle

Comment: I have removed oracle tag as it is sql server question

Comment: If it's SQL Server, please include the Sql Server tag as well as the specific version tag. SQL Server introduced native json support in 2016, so the version you need this to work with might have a significant impact on the answer provided.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and what is the exact format of your data - value like `{"customer":"customer-1","attributes":{"att-a":"att-a-7","att-b":"att-b-3","att-c":"att-c-10","att-d":"att-d-10","att-e":"att-e-15","att-f":"att-f-11","att-g":"att-g-2","att-h":"att-h-7","att-i":"att-i-5","att-j":"att-j-14"}}` for each row or something else? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov - Have updated my question with data that is currently in the SQL table and SQL version is already mentioned in my Tags.

Comment: So it's not stored as Json, but simply as columns in the table? Please [edit] your question to include [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info).

Comment: ROW_NUMBER will not work in your case, e.g. if customer-1 and customer-19 have  att-a very different (like a and z) but all other attributes are the same, customer-19 will not be in the top.

Comment: try with dense rank